# Matlab: Calculate vector lengths between different points on a rectangle

Tags: matlab, vector, geometry, rectangles

I am interested in creating a Matlab script that will consider a rectangle and allow me to calculate the length of vectors between one point and several other points placed along the perimeter of the rectangle. For example, calculating the length of all the vectors indicated in red on the image below, using point 9 as the origin.

[image]

This will need to include the ability to specify the location of each point and should be adaptable to rectangles with different dimensions. I would like to be able to calculate the vector lengths using any of the specified points as the origin. For example from point 1 to all other points on the perimeter.

I realize this is a potentially time consuming task so any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am a novice with Matlab. Look forward to seeing some ideas! Cheers.

Comment: Could you provide an example to demonstrate what you mean,please?

Comment: I dont have the "reputation" to upload a diagram....the work im doing is basically a form of tomography where we measure acoustic wave speeds along different vectors through a cylinder. there is a sensors on each end of the cylinder and 4 arranged along each side of the cylinder. Because of the geometry of the sensors, we need only consider a rectangle as a cross section through the cylinder. does that help? cheers

Comment: I have updated the post. Let me know if there's anything else I can do to clarify.

Comment: How do you specify the points? Are they given in a list or do you give the dimensions of the rectangle and then they are evenly spaced, or...?

Comment: The position of the points will be variable from one experiment to the next. I can input them in whatever way suits. A list of coordinates would be fine as long as it holds to the geometry of the rectangle. Cheers

Comment: Also, if anyone can think of a cool way too generate a plot of the vectors with their calculated lengths over the recrangle, that would also be really useful.

Comment: This question is way too broad. You need to at least provide an interface for people to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on top of @ihcgeneva's post, I would avoid using loops all together and use [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) instead.  The code by @ihcgeneva can be greatly simplified to:

```
xList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; 
yList = [5, 4, 2, 2, 1];

rootPoint = 3; %The point you want as your 'base'
Distance = sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus, [xList; yList].', [xList(rootPoint) yList(rootPoint)]).^2, 2));
```

Note that there is no need to define the anonymous function `d`.  In addition, there is also no need for a loop.  With MATLAB, you are always encouraged to [vectorize](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) your code.  What vectorization means is that there are certain functions in MATLAB that will accept an array or matrix of inputs and the function will operate on each entry individually.  The output of these functions will give you an array or matrix of the same size that has each of those values having the function applied to those elements.  It has been shown to be much faster over looping through each element in your array or matrix and applying the function to each element one at a time.  It's mostly due to function call overhead.  It would be more efficient to just call the function once rather than many times for as many elements as you want to apply the function to.

Now, the above code is quite a handful to absorb, but still pretty easy to understand once you get the hang of it.  `bsxfun` stands for **B**inary **S**ingleton E**x**pansion **Fun**ction.  If we look inside the function, we are invoking the `minus` function between a single point in your rectangle found at the index `rootPoint` with all of the other co-ordinates in the rectangle.  What we will do is place the co-ordinates into a 2D matrix where the first column denotes the `x` co-ordinate and the second column denotes the `y` co-ordinate.  Next, what `bsxfun` is doing is that it **duplicates** the point located at `rootPoint` so that it is the same size as this 2D matrix.  `bsxfun` will then do an element by element subtraction between this duplicated matrix with the original 2D matrix that you created.

This will perform the first part of the Euclidean distance where you subtract the corresponding dimensions.  This creates an output 2D matrix where the first column is the subtraction of the `x` components and the second column is the subtraction of the `y` components.  We then square each value in the matrix, then sum over the columns then take the square root, thus completing the Euclidean distance operation.  @lhcgeneva has put you on the right track where the shortest distance between the point you are looking at with the other points in the rectangle is the Euclidean distance.

---

Now if you want to plot the lines from one point to another like you have in your image, you actually don't need to calculate the lengths at all.  You just need to know where the points along the rectangle are located, show the image, then use `plot` and plot lines from each point in the rectangle to the source point.  This looks very much like an IC Pin layout diagram, so I'm going to use one that I found on the Internet:

[image]

Let's use pin #3 as the source.  I've also gone through the image and pin-pointed the location of the middle of each pin:

```
points = [49 84; 49 133; 49 178; 49 229; 49 277; 49 325; 49 372; 205 374; 205 325; 205 276; 205 228; 205 181; 205 131; 205 87];
```

The first column is the `x` or column co-ordinate while the second column is the `y` or row co-ordinate of where the centre is for each pin in this image.  Now, all you have to do is show this image, use `hold on` to make sure that you can place multiple lines on the plot without it erasing, and plot lines from the source point to each point in the matrix:

```
im = imread('http://www.infraredremote.com/images/14-pin-IC.jpg');
imshow(im);
hold on;
points = [49 84; 49 133; 49 178; 49 229; 49 277; 49 325; 49 372; 205 374; 205 325; 205 276; 205 228; 205 181; 205 131; 205 87];

rootPoint = 3;
for idx = 1 : size(points, 1)
    plot([points(rootPoint, 1) points(idx, 1)], [points(rootPoint, 2) points(idx, 2)], 'r', 'LineWidth', 5);
end
```

The above code loads in the image directly from the Internet.  We then show the image with [`imshow`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html) then use `hold on` like we talked about before.  Next, we choose our root point, which is pin 3, then we loop over all of the points and draw a line from the root point to each pin.  We make the line red, as well as making the width of the line 5 pixels thick.  In this case, we do need to loop over the points to make it easy.   We can vectorize the plotting, but it will become a bit sophisticated given your knowledge of MATLAB so far.

In any case, this is what I get:

[image]

## Edit

In your comments, you said you wanted to display the distances from the root point to each point in your rectangle.  You can do this with a loop.  Unfortunately when it comes to printing, there isn't a way to do it easily with vectorization, but looping just to print out statements should take very little time so we shouldn't worry about vectorization here.

As such, you can do something like this:

```
%// Define points along rectangle and root point
points = [49 84; 49 133; 49 178; 49 229; 49 277; 49 325; 49 372; 205 374; 205 325; 205 276; 205 228; 205 181; 205 131; 205 87];
rootPoint = 3;

%// Find distances
Distance = sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus, points, points(rootPoint,:)).^2, 2));

for idx = 1 : numel(Distance)
    fprintf('Distance between reference point %d and point %d is %f\n', ...
             rootPoint, idx, Distance(idx));
end
```

Note that I had to modify the code slightly with respect to the distances.  Because our points are now in a 2D array, the core algorithm is still the same, but I had to get the points in a slightly different way.  Specifically, I didn't need to construct the 2D matrix inside `bsxfun` as that was created already.  I can also easily extract out the root point by getting all of the columns for a single row located at the row indexed by `rootPoint`.  Next, we loop over each distance from the root point to each point in the rectangle and we simply print those out.  This is the output I get:

```
Distance between reference point 3 and point 1 is 94.000000
Distance between reference point 3 and point 2 is 45.000000
Distance between reference point 3 and point 3 is 0.000000
Distance between reference point 3 and point 4 is 51.000000
Distance between reference point 3 and point 5 is 99.000000
Distance between reference point 3 and point 6 is 147.000000
Distance between reference point 3 and point 7 is 194.000000
Distance between reference point 3 and point 8 is 250.503493
Distance between reference point 3 and point 9 is 214.347848
Distance between reference point 3 and point 10 is 184.228119
Distance between reference point 3 and point 11 is 163.816971
Distance between reference point 3 and point 12 is 156.028843
Distance between reference point 3 and point 13 is 162.926364
Distance between reference point 3 and point 14 is 180.601772
```

This looks about right, and certainly makes sense as the distance between point 3 and itself (3rd row of the print-out) is 0.

Comment: Thanks for this great feedback. Is there a simple way to get the script to print the results of the measurements with respect to the vectors? i.e print: Vector 1-2 = 10?

Comment: Do you want to print every combination or just with respect with the reference point?

Comment: heres a link for the plot I made using your script. https://www.dropbox.com/s/cd0o4ewl4zq8xin/Wave_vector_diagram_4.jpg?dl=0

Comment: You'd have to loop through all the points and print them out. When it comes to printing, it can't be vectorized!

Comment: Cool! Nice image! I'll update my answer for you in a while. I'm on my way to work.